# Double handled slider android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-layout, slider

I was wondering if anyone had some code, or knew of a place that has code for creating a double handled slider. Example : [image]

I am looking to do something similar using a double slider to search for a range of ages on a time array , like in the photo

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to build it myself... the idea I followed was different from the answers above. I created some items that can be dragged on the screen with the finger, and I fixed the Y position so it can only move from left to right. After that, I generated rectangles that signify the progress (between knobs and outside them). The good thing about this technique is that you can easily customize the slider to be vertical or horizontal, or if you want to put a custom picture in the background. The source is in the link below, and if anyone has any questions please ask.
link: [eclipse project](http://www.2shared.com/file/UNvlbTpq/DualKnobSlider.html)

[image: small resolution landscape]

[image: small resolution portrait]

[image: high resolution landscape]

Comment: Did you set up a repository somewhere besides the download link?

Comment: sorry for the late answer; I uploaded it to github: https://github.com/ovidiu-birgu/dual-knob-slider

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen the [range-seek-bar](http://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/).  It looks like it would work perfectly.!

[image: Screenshot of range-seek-bar]

Comment: no source or binaries for it

Answer (score 2):

You could try and extend the [AbsSeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html) and have a look at the single-thumbed-[SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) how it works.

Comment: Annoying how they didn't use a proper name :-) I'll definitely take a look at this. +50 for coming with the suggestion.

Comment: Are you going to make such a double-thumbed SeekBar and release it as UI-component? Would be awesome, because I (and I suppose many others too) would need such a component too ;)

Comment: @Mark'pxr'Mooibroek As you said "if i make it ill post the source on my blog p-xr.com"  Have you made this?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked through the entire [Widgets package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) and incredibly, the ADT doesn't have any slider control!  This obviously puts you at a serious disadvantage since there is nothing already implemented for you to extend or modify.

However, there is this guide on [hacking together a custom slider component out of a ProgressBar](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/custom-view-horizontalslider) component.  This might be your solution.  The author overrides the `onTouchEvent` method to set the progress bar's value according to the touch coordinates.  Very clever.  However, since a progress bar can only show one value, it's only possible to show the lower or upper bound using a single progress bar.

My suggestion is to create a compound component which has one progress bar that is always at 0%, and another progress bar which is always at 100%.  The second bar is overlaid on top of the first one, and its coordinates and width set so its left edge represents the lower bound (x), and the right edge shows the upper bound (x + width).  Your `onTouchEvent` will detect whether the touch coordinates are closer to the lower or upper bound, and then start adjusting that bound until released.  When the bounds change, you simply reposition and resize the second bar.  Provided you can position components absolutely and on top of other components, this should look great!

Comment: That'S not quite true. There is a slider, but it'S called SeekBar: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html

Comment: Well, well! Wouldn't you believe it. They did create one after all, but they decided to give it a name nobody would recognize, instead of calling it 'Slider'.  What's even more amusing is that it extends ProgressBar, just like the hacked example does.

Comment: You were on track with extending the ProgressBar +1 :-)